# Does $|x|=\pm x?$ And what is the graph of $y=|x|?$ And other questions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value

My use of "or" is as this: if $a$ or $b$ is true then $a$, and $b$ can be true together or either one of them is true and the other is false. I define $\pm x=+x$ or $-x.$

With these definitions, I want to ask

1. What is the graph of $y=\pm x?$
2. Does $|x|=\pm x,$ in general? In general, because it is true for values like $x=5$ i.e. $|5|=\pm 5$ is true.
3. If we replace $|x|\rightarrow \pm x$ in a sentence then will the new statement be equivalent to the original one? For e.g. is it true $y=|x|\iff y=\pm x?$
4. Is it true that $|x|=|y|\implies x=\pm y?$

Comment: Replacing $|x|$ by $\pm x$ is not equivalent. However $y=|x| \implies y=\pm x$. You are confusing equivalence and implication.

Comment: @Carlaonlyprovestrivialprop I intended to use \iff but used \implies.

Comment: Then it's not true. For example $-1 = \pm 1$, however $-1 \neq |1|$.

Comment: I don't understand why $|x| = \pm x$.

Comment: $\pm x$ cannot be recognized as the notation of some element. This in contrast with $|x|$. So setting them equal makes no sense.

Comment: @drhab what do you mean by "notation of some element"?

Comment: It is usual to say things as: "let $x$ denote an element of $\mathbb R$". But we cannot say things like: "let $\pm x$ denote an element of $\mathbb R$". The notation $\pm x$ can be used in some situations as a shorthand, but is not rigorous enough to use in a setting like $|x|=\pm x$. On LHS we easily recognize the function $x\mapsto|x|$ but on RHS we cannot recognize any function. That's why expressions like $|x|=\pm x$ on their own (so not in the context of an implication) make no sense. Beware that $|5|=5$ (a number) and $\pm 5$ is not a number. So you cannot say things like $|5|=\pm5$.

Comment: @drhab Often $y=\pm x$ is used as a shorthand for $y=x$ or $y=-x$.

Comment: @drhab but I have defined $\pm 5=+5$ or $-5$, and with the "or" in the sense as described in the first para, it is true that $|5|=\pm 5.$

Comment: It is not true that $|5|=+5\text{ or }-5$. The absolute value of $5$ is $5$ and nothing else. You can at most say that equality $|x|=5$ has the solutions $5$ and $-5$.

Comment: @drhab this equality is used on [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Definition_and_properties) in the para starting with "Non-negativity, positive definiteness".

Comment: There it is said that $|x|=x$ **if** $x$ is non-negative and $|x|=-x$ otherwise. So two cases are discerned. Statements like $|x|=\pm x$ of $|5|=\pm5$ are not found there.

Comment: @drhab you're right that +5  or −5 is not a number and hence |5| isn't also, and hence cant equal ±5. But when I say that |5|=±5 I mean "5=5 or 5=-5", which is true.

Comment: @drhab I meant this paragraph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKp2o.png

Comment: and particularly this part: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdYOL.png

Comment: It is certainly not for nothing that there they write "$|a+b|=s(a+b)$ where $s=\pm1$" instead of "$|a+b|=\pm(a+b)$". The second expression is wrong and is deliberately avoided. I stop commenting on this now.

Comment: @drhab Thank you for your giving me your so precious time. I am very grateful.

Comment: $|\cdot |$ is a function, it takes a unique input and produces a unique output. Hence $|5|=5$ and nothing else. If you want to redefine it as having "5 or -5" as output, then you're going against established standard notation and terminology and inventing your own.

Answer (score 0):

($\bigstar$) **Abosulute Value** ($\bigstar$)
So when it comes to the graph  you can see an image using Desmos here:[image: Graph]

---

**Explanations**

> When it comes to $|x|=y$ it is always true that $\ x=\pm y $.
> It is true that: |-5|=|5|=5 so |5|=$\pm 5$ is wrong.
> it is also true that $y=|x|\implies y=\pm x$ so  regarding to your question 4, replacing it's wrong.
> Last but not least, it is true that $|x|=|y|\implies x=\pm y$ but it also true that:$|x|=|y|\implies y=\pm x$.

Comment: You affirm something and then deny it in the next sentence.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: it is also *true* that y=|x|⟹y=±x so replacing it it's *wrong*. Is it true or false?

Comment: When i said "replacing it it's wrong" i was referring to your question 4